# Fill SVG only if existing fill colour is certain value

Tags: jquery, svg

I am using this code to change the fill colour of an SVG object and it works:

```
  $(function() {
      $('g').mouseenter(function () {
              $('path, rect, circle', this).attr('fill', '#00C8C8');
      })
  });
```

But, I only want to change the fill colour if the existing fill colour is of  a certain value. So, I thought something like this:

```
  $(function() {
      $('g').mouseenter(function () {
          if($('circle', this).attr('fill') == '#DCDCFF'){
              $('circle', this).attr('fill', '#00C8C8');
          }
      })
  });
```

EDIT: ...again, slight error in the jsfiddle (thanks Robert)

I've created a page on jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wc9ZE/4/

to show what I'm trying to get at, I've also made the colours more distinct.

The problem is, all the rectangles turn yellow then red, I only want the large one that was originally yellow to turn red then back to yellow. The little white rectangle should remain white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your brackets are in the wrong place

```
if($('path, rect, circle', this).attr('fill') == '#DCDCFF') {
```

And the jsfiddle seems rather strange as in the first circle case you're using val rather than attr i.e.

```
if ($('circle', this).val('fill')
```

should be

```
if ($('circle', this).attr('fill')
```

shouldn't it?

And finally if you only want it to work on one rect then you should give that rect an id attribute (below I've assumed id="r") and then change the code like this...

```
  $(function () {
      $('g').mouseenter(function () {
          if ($('circle', this).attr('fill') == 'yellow') {
              $('circle', this).attr('fill', 'pink');
          }
          if ($('#r', this).attr('fill') == 'red') {
              $('#r', this).attr('fill', 'yellow');
          }
      }).mouseleave(function () {
          if ($('#r', this).attr('fill') == 'yellow') {
              $('#r', this).attr('fill', 'red');
          }
          if ($('circle', this).attr('fill') == 'pink') {
              $('circle', this).attr('fill', 'yellow');
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for that. Unfortunately, this still doesn't work as expected. I have edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: Whoops! You're right. I've just made a change to the jsfiddle. The problem is, all the rectangles turn yellow then red, I only want the large one that was originally yellow to turn red then back.

Answer (score 2):

sorry if i sound like stupid .. i think i am wrong here and i am sorry if so

but what i understand from you question is that , only big rectangle color should change but not smaller one. this can be done very easily by giving diffrent id to both rectangle.

please see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53Fjf/)

sample code as below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script>
              $(function () {
                  $('g').mouseenter(function () {
                      if ($('circle', this).attr('fill') == 'yellow') {
                          $('circle', this).attr('fill', 'pink');
                      }
                      if ($('rect', this).attr('fill') == 'red') {
                          $('#ttt33', this).attr('fill', 'yellow');
                      }
                  }).mouseleave(function () {
                      if ($('rect', this).attr('fill') == 'yellow') {
                          $('#ttt33', this).attr('fill', 'red');
                      }
                      if ($('circle', this).attr('fill') == 'pink') {
                          $('circle', this).attr('fill', 'yellow');
                      }
                  });
              });
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <svg version="1.1" width="250px" height="200px" viewBox="0, 0, 350, 250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <g id="S1">
                <rect x="20" y="55" width="220" height="95" fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" id="ttt33" />
                <rect x="20" y="80" width="30" height="40" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" id="ttt22" />
                <line x1="20" y1="100" x2="50" y2="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
                <line x1="50" y1="100" x2="70" y2="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
                <circle cx="105" cy="100" r="35" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
            </g>
        </svg>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Dhaval. This seems to be exactly what I'm after! I need to adjust my XML, but I can manage that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not what you're looking for, but for the fun of it:  Using CSS3, you can change the color on hover if a specific fill attribute is set (try on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/AWOlUYa/9/)):

```
<svg xmln="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="90">
  <style type="text/css">
    rect:hover[fill="#DCDCFF"]{fill:#00C8C8}
  </style>
  <rect width="40" height="40" fill="#DCDCFF"/>
  <rect y="50" width="40" height="40"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi Thomas. This works in Firefox but I can't get it to work in IE.

Comment: You're right.  It doesn't even work in Chrome, Chrome doesn't like the `*` selector here.  It works there with `rect`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Since SVG handles `fill` and `stroke` both as "style" attributes and via the "SVGPaint" api (which is deprecated), the safest way to retrieve the value of a presentation attribute is [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle), which is run against the `window` and the element is passed in:

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(base_dom_element).fill
```

Or:

```
  $(function() {
      $('g').mouseenter(function () {
          var dom_elem = $('circle',this).get(0);
          if(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(dom_elem).fill == '#dcdcff'){
              $('circle', this).css('fill', '#00C8C8');
          }
      })
  });
```

Also, in Chrome at least, the value is returned as a lowercase rgb hex value, so you may want to change the case of the value before comparing it to keep it cross browser friendly.

Did you originally try simply:

```
$('circle', this).css('fill');
```

Comment: IE returns a hex value, Firefox returns a rgba(r, g, b, a) value so it's pretty hard to do it this way cross-browser.