# How to get value of fill attribute of SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

How i can get value of fill attriute of svg in java-script or jquery.

```
if($(this).find('svg').attr('fill') == '#bfbfbf')
```

This code is not helping me  .

Comment: This question is not answerable with such code. can you add more to it? and it is not necessary about the color code, that might be interpreted differently on browsers like `rgba(), hex()` etc.

Comment: I have svg element inside a div and i want to toggle or change color of svg based on current color of svg.   This is what i am trying where scope is reference to that clicked div                                                                  // if($(scope).find('svg').attr('fill') == '#bfbfbf') 
      // {
      //     $(scope).find('svg').css({ fill: "gold" });
      // }
      // else if($(scope).find('svg').attr('fill') == 'gold') 
      // {
      //   $(scope).find('svg').css({ fill: "#bfbfbf" });
      // }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill SVG only if existing fill colour is certain value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590985/fill-svg-only-if-existing-fill-colour-is-certain-value)

Answer (score 2):

Depending of the svg structure there are two ways to get the fill

get the attribute fill

```
document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].getAttribute("fill");
```

get the fill from the style

```
document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].style.fill
```